# Calling user space API functions from a windows KMD?

Tags: c++, windows, api

I would like to call user space windows API functions from a KMD (Kernel mode driver) but I'm not sure where to go from here. I searched for "windows KMD inverted call" but couldn't find anything. I know a little bit about IRPs and such but not enough to be able to figure it out on my own. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: kernel mode can not direct call code in user mode. he can cooperate with user mode code only, but user mode code must be designed for this cooperation

Answer (score 1):

You need a helper service in user mode that makes the call for your driver. The [inverted call model](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=94) has been used on WinNT for ages and can also be used in [with KMDF](https://www.osr.com/nt-insider/2013-issue1/inverted-call-model-kmdf/).

Search the [OSR mailing list](http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=search) for endless discussions about this model and other alternatives.